# How can I loop through ID inside jquery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, mysqli

I looped through the list of doctors in my area from the database and displayed on my page, now I want to load those doctors "About doctor" content inside the bootstrap modal. I created an "about" column inside the same database table where doctors data reside in, now I want to load each doctor "About Us" content when users click on to "see details"(see Image) link.

jquery click event

```
$('.see-details').on('click',function(){
$('.modal-body').load('getContent.php?id=<?php echo ?>',function(){
    $('#myModal').modal({show:true});
});
```

});

getabout.php

```
    if($query->num_rows > 0){
    $row = $query->fetch_assoc();
    echo '<p>'.$row['about'].'</p>';
}else{
    echo 'About Us not found....';
}
```

how can I echo id dynamically from the database?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This isn't where you want to output the ID:

```
$('.modal-body').load('getContent.php?id=<?php echo ?>',function(){
```

Because this code should only exist *once* on the page, not be copied for every element.  Instead, you want to output the ID somewhere that this code can *get* that value.  The ideal place is likely the `.see-details` element itself.  So presumably you have some kind of element for clicking, let's go with this:

```
echo '<button class="see-details">See Details</button>';
```

And presumably this is being output to the page in a loop in your PHP code, and *that loop* has access to the ID values.  In that case, you can output those values to the page right there.  Something structurally like this:

```
echo '<button class="see-details" data-id="' . $id . '">See Details</button>';
```

Which would produce something like:

```
<button class="see-details" data-id="123">See Details</button>
```

Now in the click handler for that element you can fetch that ID value and use it in the URL.  Something like this:

```
$('.see-details').on('click', function(){
    var id = $(this).data('id');
    $('.modal-body').load('getContent.php?id=' + id, function(){
        $('#myModal').modal({show:true});
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution :) very neatly explained. Modified as you suggested and it works very well :D Thank You